# SceneKit Node To Follow Camera

Tags: ios, scenekit

I am attempting to have a text node in SceneKit always point towards me - that is towards my camera location. For some reason it does not rotate but stays static:

```
let text = SCNText(string: "My String", extrusionDepth: 0.1)
text.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 10)
let textNode = SCNNode(geometry: text)
textNode.position = position

//Here I add the constraint to the SCNView's pointOfView node
let lookAtConstraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: scnView.pointOfView)
textNode.constraints = [lookAtConstraint]
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you creating a heads-up display?

Comment: I suspect I could help you solve your issue if you answer my question. I'm trying to determine what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Sorry was off on business. Yes trying a hud. Am now using a SCN BillboardConstraint. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a type of constraint for this specific purpose.
It's called `SCNBillboardConstraint` and it always orients the node it is assigned to towards the current camera. You don't even have to provide a target when initializing.

Comment: Thanks that is what I was missing!